# Sen2Cor into Google Earth Engine Workflow

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, sen2cor

I'm running a script to detect contaminated water on sentinel-2 timeseries data, and I need to expand my research to include before 2019. I've tried using sen2cor through the command line, though have only got a single image at a time to work with the line:

`L2A_Process.bat FILEPATH.SAFE --tif`

Ideally I would expand that to be able to batch process the 40 images I have downloaded, but it is not the biggest problem in the world.

What is the biggest problem in the world is my inability to load the resulting tiffs into GEE. It fails every time with the error 'Error: Total area of overlap between input files is too large: 3.00e+00 of the total mosaic area. This overlap may not exceed 5.00e-01. (Error code: 3)'

Is there an established workflow for this kind of process? Any wise advise would be much appreciated.